# Are F# lists persistent?

Tags: f#, performance, immutability, persistent

I'm a C# developer new to F#,I understand that in .net  the strings are immutable. In other words every time you modify a string you get a new string instance.

For a non functional mind like mine the first question would be efficiency and I understand that C# mutable objects are not persistent. since string manipulation is normally trivial in most of applications.

My question is, Is this the case for F# lists too?, Do F# clones every list on change? Like for example, when filtering a list do I create a new list with fewer Items?

**Update**: I'm not comparing .net string and lists. I named string as an example of an immutable object and want to know if F# provides any special treatment for it's List.

This is what I mean by "[persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)".

Comment: .Net strings are immutable, it has nothing to do with C#. C#, VB.Net, and any other .Net language will all have immutable strings because it's the same code library and eventually the same IL regardless of the language.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the title because **immutable data structure** is the term usually applied to functional programming lists, maps, etc, whereas **persistent objects** have a second meaning in database sense.

Comment: I'agree, yet it's the standard term in data structure implementation jargon.

Comment: While I fully understand your curiosity. Efficiency should be the last thing you worry about when writing code. You can re-implement something that runs twice as slow as the original, but it can be run on 4 processors at the same time. It is now twice as fast as the original.

Comment: I couldn't agree more but it's always best to know what happens behind the scene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [Dustin Campbell's introduction](http://diditwith.net/2008/03/03/WhyILoveFListsTheBasics.aspx) does an amazing job of explaining list immutability.

> In the functional world, lists are immutable. This means that node sharing is possible because the original lists will never change. Because the first list ends with the empty list, its nodes must be copied in order to point its last node to the second list. After the append operation, our lists look like so:
>
> [image]
>
> At this point, the more skeptical among you might be saying, "Well,
>   that's a pretty interesting theory, but can you prove it?"
>
> No problem.
>
> Using the knowledge that F# lists are recursive, we can retrieve the
>   last half of combined (the inner list starting at 4) by taking the
>   tail, of its tail, of its tail. List.tl is the function that F#
>   provides for extracting a list's tail.
>
> ```
> > let lastHalf = List.tl (List.tl (List.tl combined));;
>
> val lastHalf : int list
>
> > lastHalf;;
>
> val it : int list = [4; 5; 6]
> ```
>
> Finally, because F# is first-class citizen of the .NET Framework, we
>   have full access to all of the base class libraries. So, we can use
>   the `Object.ReferenceEquals` method to test whether or not lastHalf
>   and second are indeed the same instance.
>
> ```
> > System.Object.ReferenceEquals(lastHalf, second);;
>
> val it : bool = true
> ```
>
> And there you have it. Believe it or not, appending two immutable
>   lists can actually be faster and more memory efficient than appending
>   mutable lists because fewer nodes have to be copied.

Comment: Sadly, the link you provided is dead :( Update suggestion using internet archive : https://web.archive.org/web/20150710063910/http://diditwith.net/2008/03/03/WhyILoveFListsTheBasics.aspx

Answer (score 1):

F# lists are immutable.  There are no APIs to 'modify' an F# list, so there is no cloning involved.  Operations like `List.filter` do create a new list (which might share some structure with the original, if possible).

(This is how all immutable objects in any language work, I think.)

See e.g.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure

for a nice description along with pictures that suggest how sharing works.

Comment: I'm exactly interested in the "might share" part. Can you explain when it is possible?

Comment: Added a link to an article with useful pretty pictures.

Comment: In the case of lists, since they're just linked list, when you append an element a new list is created, however in reality only head is set to point to the new value and tail is set to point to the existing list. Other operations like filters and maps require the list to be recreated.

Comment: To be clear, @emaster means that when you cons and element onto the front of a list, you can share the entire 'tail' with the original list.  (Appending to the end of the list requires a full copy.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the references from Dan and Brian should directly answer your question. If you want to find out more, you can also look at the following materials (published just this week at MSDN) that were written to explain F# and functional concepts to .NET developers:

- [Tutorial: Working with Functional Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297099.aspx) introduces F# lists and shows how to implement the same concept in C#, which is a great way to understand how lists work (and which operations are efficient).
- [Overview: Working with Immutable Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297115.aspx) gives some more background information on immutability in F# - it doesn't directly answer your question, but may be a useful resource too.

Answer (score 0):

F# lists are linked lists. So when you *create* a new list it simply adds the item to the existing list and points to the head, which contains the new item. The original list still points to the item that was the head at the time that list was created. So in other words, they all point to the same list at different spots within the list.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand lists in functional languages to understand [Cons Cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons)